# How to properly repeat an entire song which already has with repeats?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, repeats

What is the best way to repeat an entire song, including the first and second ending? Basically, I have a very short song that I would like to play through two times, which means also playing through the first and second ending two times. I thought adding a D.C. al Coda at the end of the second ending might be the correct way, but I'm not sure if you can do that. Can you put a D.C. al Coda at the end with no other coda sign in the piece?

Comment: Is it also allowed to play it 3 times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good way to denote nested repeats?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74096/is-there-a-good-way-to-denote-nested-repeats/74124#74124)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the second ending write "Da capo con ripetizione". That means da capo with repetition.

If the coda follows right after the second ending it is obvious that you should continue with the coda after you have finished playing the whole thing da capo.

Elaboration: You can include the coda by writing this:

Da capo con ripetizione, e poi la coda

Comment: I would only use Italian for very well established conventions (DC al fine, DS al coda, etc.). Having to put instructions into google translate (or speak Italian) to know what to do is overly burdensome. DC con ripetizione is probably fine since it is short, pretty well established and easily googlable. I think most people will interpret "from the beginning with repetitions" as implicitly including the coda as well.

Comment: @WillRoss1 you don't need google translate for this, neither do you need to speak Italian (which I don't). Just google "e poi la coda"
https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-samsung-gn-rev1&source=android-browser&q="e+poi+la+coda" and you will find out. Anyway, in this particular case in this topic it seems to be rather self evident after the da capo repetitions to continue to the coda whether there is a note on it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would to write  "Play twice" at the top.